# How to append items to a list one time each in python

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, append

Lets say I have a list called my_list and a function called my_function and my_function appends items to my_list based on which portion of the surface gameDisplay was clicked on. However whenever you hold down the mouse for more than one frame, it appends more than one of that item to my_list. This is not the result I am going for. I was wondering if there was a way you could do this without appending more than one of each item to my_list

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Maybe can you use `set()`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show code but I guess you use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` which gives `True` all the time when you keep button pressed. And this can be your problem.

You can do one of two things:

use `event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` which is created only once - when button change state from `not-pressed` into `pressed`.

Or:

use extra variable which will remeber `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` from previous frame. And then compare if now button is pressed but in previous frame was not-pressed then add element to list.

---

**EDIT:** old code from different question which use `event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to change color.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856739/how-to-cycle-3-images-on-a-rect-button

import pygame

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))

# - objects -

# create three images with different colors
images = [
    pygame.Surface((100,100)),    
    pygame.Surface((100,100)),    
    pygame.Surface((100,100)),    
]    

images[0].fill((255,0,0))
images[1].fill((0,255,0))
images[2].fill((0,0,255))

images_rect = images[0].get_rect()

# choose first image
index = 0

# - mainloop -

running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if event.button == 1 and images_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # cycle index
                index = (index+1) % 3

    # - draws -

    screen.blit(images[index], images_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

GitHub: [furas/python-examples/pygame/button-click-cycle-color](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color)